# Problemas com oJsonObj:Json_Hash

Tags: advpl

Eu sou nova com advpl, e preciso criar um objeto HashMap. Vou deixar parte do meu código para ver se vocês pode me ajudar.

```
If !empty(cJsonCOT)
    // Cria o objeto para fazer o parser do Json
    oJsonObj := tJsonParser():New()

    // Faz o Parser da mensagem JSon e extrai para Array (aJsonfields) e cria tambem um HashMap para os dados da mensagem (oJHM)
    lRet := oJsonObj:Json_Hash(cStrJson, nLenStrJson, @aJsonfields, @nRetParser, @oJHashMap)

        If ( !lRet )
            MsgStop(cStrJson,"Falha ao solicitar dados")
        else
            // Obtem o valor dos campos usando o Hashmap gerado
            HMGet(oJHashMap, "erro", @lCotERRO)
            If lCotERRO
                MsgStop("##### [JSON][ERR] " + "Parser com erro" + " MSG len: " + AllTrim(Str(nLenStrJson)) + " bytes lidos: " + AllTrim(Str(nRetParser)))
            Else
                // Obtem o valor dos campos usando a chave
                HMGet(oJHashMap, "valorCompra", cCompra)
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    // Limpa os objetos utilizados
    FreeObj(oJsonObj)
    FreeObj(oJHashMap)
ENDIF
```

A única coisa que não consigo é criar o objeto -> @oJHashMap

Todas as variáveis ​​são declaradas de acordo com seu tipo.

Todos esses parâmetros estão bem (StrJson, nLenStrJson, @aJsonfields, @nRetParser). Eles têm seus dados corretos.

lRet := oJsonObj:Json_Hash(cStrJson, nLenStrJson, @aJsonfields, @nRetParser, @oJHashMap) -> Mas nesta linha, de acordo com a teoria (que eu obviamente não entendo), esse objeto deve ser criado. Mas isso não acontece, apenas não tem nada.

Esse código é apenas um exemplo. A partir desse objeto, preciso de vários dados. Que no exemplo eu estou procurando apenas um. Porque o meu problema é que o objeto não está sendo criado por algum motivo.

Comment: Daregny, você seu objetivo é apenas pegar o valorCompra do JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em ADVPL, é possível fazer o parser de um JSON de mais de uma forma.

Podemos utilizar o hashmap e o TJsonParser como você estava implementando, porém também é possível utilizar o JSONObject, que deixa o código bem mais simples.

Aqui um exemplo, usando o seu código para retornar o valorCompra, e também uma implementação utilizando o JSONObject:

```
#include "protheus.ch"

user function JSONExample()
local cStrJson as char

cStrJson := '{"valorCompra": "1.075,80"}'

//TJsonParser e Hashmap
ConOut( getVlrHashMap( cStrJson) )

cStrJson := '{"value":[{"cotacaoCompra": 4.13700, "cotacaoVenda": 4.13760, "dataHoraCotacao": "2019-10-18 13:09:37.206"}]}'

//JSONObject
ConOut( getVlrJSONObj( cStrJson) )

return nil

static function getVlrHashMap(cJSON)
local cCompra as char
local nLenStrJson as numeric
local aJsonfields as array
local nRetParser as numeric
local lRet as logical
local oJsonObj as object
local oJHashMap as object
local lCotERRO as logical

//EXEMPLO UTILIZANDO TJsonParser E Hashmap
if !Empty(cJSON)
    // Cria o objeto para fazer o parser do Json
    oJsonObj := TJsonParser():New()
    nLenStrJson := Len(cJSON)
    aJsonfields := {}
    nRetParser := 0

    // Faz o Parser da mensagem JSon e extrai para Array (aJsonfields) e cria tambem um HashMap para os dados da mensagem (oJHM)
    lRet := oJsonObj:Json_Hash(cJSON, nLenStrJson, @aJsonfields, @nRetParser, @oJHashMap)

    if ( !lRet )
        MsgStop(cJSON,"Falha ao solicitar dados")
    else
        // Obtem o valor dos campos usando o Hashmap gerado
        HMGet(oJHashMap, "erro", @lCotERRO)

        if lCotERRO
            //É possível utilizar cValToChar no lugar de AllTrim(Str(nLenStrJson))
            MsgStop("##### [JSON][ERR] " + "Parser com erro" + " MSG len: " + AllTrim(Str(nLenStrJson)) + " bytes lidos: " + AllTrim(Str(nRetParser)))
        else
            // Obtem o valor dos campos usando a chave
            HMGet(oJHashMap, "valorCompra", @cCompra)
        endif
    endif

    // Limpa os objetos utilizados
    FreeObj(oJsonObj)
    FreeObj(oJHashMap)
endif

return cCompra

static function getVlrJSONObj(cJSON)
local cCompra as char
local cError as char
local jJSON

//EXEMPLO UTILIZANDO JSONObject
if !Empty(cJSON)
    //Classe responsável por trabalhar com JSON em ADVPL
    jJSON := JSONObject():New()

    //Efetuar o parser do JSON
    cError := jJSON:FromJSON(cJSON)

    //Se vazio, não foi gerado erro no parser
    if Empty(cError)
        //Sintaxe simples, mais próximo ao utilizado em JS
        cCompra := jJSON['value'][1]['cotacaoCompra']
    else
        MsgStop("Parser error: " + cError)
    endif
endif

return cCompra
```

A função getVlrHashMap é com base em seu código, já a getVlrJSONObj utiliza o JSONObject.

---

Referências:

https://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/Classe+JsonObject

https://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/Classe+TJsonParser

https://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/HMGet

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda... Mas não funciona... :(... Eu acho que meu problema é o próprio json.

Comment: Gerou algum erro de parser? Precisa verificar como está esse JSON, se ele estiver com algum erro, nenhuma das formas vai funcionar.

Comment: Vou colocar os detalhes para que você possa ver.

Answer (score 0):

A função fico assim.

```
Static function GetVlrJSONObj(cJsonCOT)
Local cCotCompra, cErro
Local oJsonObj

If !Empty(cJsonCOT)
    //Classe responsável por trabalhar com JSON em ADVPL
    oJsonObj := JSONObject():New()

    //Efetuar o parser do JSON
    cError := oJsonObj:FromJSON(cJsonCOT)

    //Se vazio, não foi gerado erro no parser
    if Empty(cErro)
        //Sintaxe simples, mais próximo ao utilizado em JS
        cCotCompra := oJsonObj['cotacaoCompra']
    else
        MsgStop("Parser error: " + cError)
    endif
endif
```

Return cCotCompra

[image: E este é o Json e o resultado.]

Comment: Coloca o JSON recebido nela aqui, mas não em imagem. Ao chamar a função, gerou erro de parser?

Comment: Não gera erro porque a variável tem um "J". Na imagem está o Json (cJsonCot) no formato String e o resultado quando o transformamos no objeto (oJsonObj).

Comment: O Json vem do uma API -> https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/PTAX/versao/v1/odata/CotacaoDolarDia(dataCotacao=@dataCotacao)?%40dataCotacao=%2709-30-2019%27&$format=json

Comment: Daregny, alterei o exemplo com um JSON igual ao seu, dê uma olhada, mas no gera, acontece que para pegar o valor cotacaoCompra, é necessário acessar a propriedade value (array) e na primeira posição do mesmo, pegar então o valor cotacaoCompra: cCompra := jJSON['value'][1]['cotacaoCompra']

Comment: Muito Obrigada!!!!!!! Você estava certo ... Desculpe minha ignorância, a verdade é a primeira vez que trabalho com um Json ...

Comment: Show! Só fica atenta que eu fixei as posições no exemplo pra sempre pegar a primeira posição do array etc. =)